# Comparing data in array of objects using a member boolean function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, boolean

First I need to compare the date of births in the array with the **operator==** function which is in the class Person, and also show the person with the earliest date of birth with the **operator<** function which is also in class Person. But I have trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong.

I was thinking of showing the earliest date of birth **operator<** using the same way as I did with **operator==** but now that it doesn't work, I have no idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Birth_date
{
private:
    unsigned int day{};
    unsigned int month{};
    unsigned int year{};

public:
    Birth_date() {}
    
    Birth_date(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        this->day = day;
        this->month = month;
        this->year = year;
    }
    
    Birth_date(const Birth_date& birth) 
    {
        day = birth.day;
        month = birth.month;
        year = birth.year;
    }

    void set_day(int day)
    {
        this->day = day;
    }
    void set_month(int month)
    {
        this->month = month;
    }
    void set_year(int year)
    {
        this->year = year;
    }

    int get_day()
    {
        return day;
    }
    int get_month()
    {
        return month;
    }
    int get_year()
    {
        return year;
    }

    friend bool operator == (const Birth_date& a, const Birth_date& b)
    {
        return (a == b);
    }
    bool operator < (const Birth_date& bd)
    {
        return day < bd.day && month < bd.month && year < bd.year;
    }
    bool operator > (const Birth_date& bd)
    {
        return day > bd.day && month > bd.month && year > bd.year;
    }
    
    ostream& Output(ostream& out)
    {
        out << "Date of birth: " << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;
        return out;
    }
};

class Person
{
private:
    string name;
    Birth_date dob;

public:
    Person() {}

    Person(string name, Birth_date dob)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->dob = dob;
    }

    Person(const Person& p)
    {
        name = p.name;
        dob = p.dob;
    }

    string get_name()
    {
        return name;
    }
    Birth_date get_dob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    bool operator < (const Person& p)const
    {
        Birth_date bd1 = p.dob;
        Birth_date bd2 = p.dob;

        return (bd1 < bd2);
    }
    bool operator == (const Person& p)const
    {
        return (dob == p.dob);
    }

    const ostream& output(ostream& out)
    {
        out << "Name: " << name << "\t" ;
        dob.Output(out);
        return out;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Person students[5] = { Person("Ivan Petkov",Birth_date(10,6,1999)),
                           Person("Gabe Trent",Birth_date(20,12,1996)),
                           Person("Maggy Sommer",Birth_date(5,2,2000)),
                           Person("Cameron Dallas",Birth_date(1,4,2001)),
                           Person("Catherine Crumb",Birth_date(28,8,2000)) };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        students[i].output(cout);
    }

    cout << "\n";


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int x = i + 1; x < 5; x++)
        {
            if (students[i].operator==(students[x]))
            {
                cout << "Students " << students[i].get_name()
                    << "and " << students[x].get_name()
                    << "have the same date of birth." << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "Nobody has the same date of birth." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Right now the only output is the array and then the program just exits.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see why the program exits? Anyway `bd1` is initialized in the same way as `bd2`, is that typo with `p.bod`?

Comment: Well the first mistake is all these `set` methods. Don't do that. Then why are you writing `students[i].operator==(students[x])`? The point of having overloaded operators is that you can write `students[i] == students[x]`, otherwise you are better off with a different name for your function, such as `students[i].compare(students[j])`. The constructors should not generally have assignments in the function body, read about [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: Your `<` and `>` operators for the date class are wrong. Read about [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Cartesian_products).

Comment: Last but not least, run your program in the debugger. You should start learning how to use the debugger yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

When you're comparing dates there's the possibility that the year and the month are the same but the day is different.

21/4/2003 > 20/4/2003

however in your code you check that the month and year are greater and can't be equal.

`return day < bd.day && month < bd.month && year < bd.year;`

by your code if the dates are: 29/1/2000 and 1/3/2000 it would return false.

your functions should first check if the years are not the same, if they are then you next check the months and then the days.

Here's an example of a code I once wrote:

```
bool MyDate::operator >(const MyDate& d)const {
if (year < d.year)
    return false;
else if (year > d.year)
    return true;
else if (year == d.year) {
    if (month < d.month)
        return false;
    else if (month > d.month)
        return true;
    if (month == d.month) {
        if (day < d.day)
            return false;
        else if (day > d.day)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: Or you can use one line, `return std::tuple(year, month, day) > std::tuple(other.year, other.month, other.day)`.

Comment: Maybe, I assume he CAN'T use tuple library since when I wrote my code I wasn't allowed to use libraries only the ones that I have been provided.